# Update multiple rows/columns in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have the following line:

```
$reset = "UPDATE pidgeon SET obt='" . $hour . "' WHERE tag='" . $tag . "'";
```

Which updates just fine. However I need to update an additional row (kill) and I keep getting syntax errors. I've tried the following:

```
$reset = "UPDATE pidgeon SET obt='" . $hour . "', kill='1' WHERE tag='" . $tag . "'";

$reset = "UPDATE pidgeon SET kill='1', obt='" . $hour . "' WHERE tag='" . $tag . "'";

$reset = "UPDATE pidgeon SET obt='" . $hour . "', kill='" . $num . "' WHERE tag='" . $tag . "'";
```

I've even done 2 separate UPDATE queries and I get the same syntax error message. I've narrowed it down to the system having issue with the *kill* row but I'm not sure what's the issue. I've tried setting *kill* as INT, SMALLINT, BOOL, even CHAR and trying to use 't/f' as values for it. I still get a syntax error. Any suggestions?

Comment: What syntax error are you getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KILL` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), so you'll have to enclose it in backticks, like so:

```
$reset = sprintf("UPDATE pidgeon SET `kill`='1', obt='%s' 
WHERE tag='%s'", $hour, $tag);
```

Comment: @AlexP: Absolutely. It's always better to use a more descriptive column name.

Comment: You are the best! Thank you so much! Its always the silliest errors.

Answer (score 0):

`Kill` is actually a syntax, you can't use them directly.

Just replace `kill` with another name.